# Remove numbers on a html page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to make some jQuery actions on a html page :

The page is : http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/HelloHandler.html

my aim is to remove the numbers (represented by the class jxr_linenumber)

What I've tried is :

```
$(".jxr_linenumber").text("")
```

However google chrome said : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function(…)!!

Even more ... when I tried this command $('a'), it returns with one element only ... however the page contains several "a" tags

Here is two screenshots to explain the issue and my goal

The screenshot of the actual page : 
[image]

My goal = remove the numbers using jquery ... the numbers are in the red box ....
So the result should be as follow :

[image]

Any help ? thanks

Comment: You might simply take the source from the official git repsoitory: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/ac24196b0d341534793308d585161381d5bca4ac/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/HelloHandler.java

Comment: Good seen @Daniel ... however what I've wanted to know is why my commands aren't working ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.remove()` should do the trick, but my guess is that its causing some issues since `jquery` isnt available on the page, and injecting it after, might be why its only removing one at a time.

You could use plain javascript like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("jxr_linenumber");

while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Christian .. Yes Jquery isnt available in the page .. so I'll take your answer as the correct one ... thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try the Jquery function `.remove( )` instead.  Something like

`$(".jxr_linenumber").remove( );`

Comment: OK.  I can take a longer look at it later if no one else answers.

Comment: Ok , cool .. by the way, the command that you suggested remove numbers line by line .. I want a commande that I execute it only one time! thanks

Comment: @taboubim This answer is correct. The page you are referring to doesn't import the jquery libraries, so you aren't going to be doing any jquery anything

Comment: Actually I understand the issue .. Thanks @ChiralMichael

Answer (score 0):

You use...

```
$(".jxr_linenumber").html("")
```

but in the end, the best answer is to use `$(".jxr_linenumber").remove()` since you don't want empty 'a' tags on your page.  That's just bad design.